# How to share files using drive-sdk?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I would like to know how to share a file with a user using drive-sdk and python. I have been using the code bellow, but it doesn't share the file with the specified user nor does it generate errors:

```
...

Permission = {
  'value': 'user@example.com',
  'type' : 'user',
  'role' : 'reader'
}

drive.permissions().insert(fileId=file['id'], body = Permission,sendNotificationEmails = True )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because you failed to execute it. It should be

```
drive.permissions().insert(fileId=file['id'], body=Permission, sendNotificationEmails=True ).execute()
```